# ajax request and robots.txt

Tags: ajax, bash, firefox, robots.txt

A website has a URL http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=FUNCTIOn_NAME.  When I click the URL, it executes the ajax function.

When I put the URL in the address bar, it gives a redirect error because the URL doesn't actually take you anywhere, but it definitely still executes the ajax function.

When I use the command line bash call: firefox -new-window http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=FUNCTIOn_NAME, it opens a empty page except for the line "Bad user...".  After some digging I found that the robots.txt file has "Disalow: /wp-admin/".  I am assuming this is why it isn't working in the command line.  I have used wget -e robots=off URL before, but there isn't anything to download so it doesn't apply here.

What type of URL is this? (I believe it's dynamic or formula, but not sure)

I want to get the same results with the command line as when I plug the URL into the address bar.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing special it just display a that html no matter what.  HTTP servers don't have use files. It could be written in c++, java, python or nodejs(probably not).